# Salesforce Metdata API: Retrieve translations for standard fields

Tags: metadata-api, translation

Is it possible to retrieve translations for standard fields like Account.Name, Contact.Email, etc? I've tried the following approach, but it still only returns custom fields in **objectTranslations** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <members>Account.Name</members>
        <members>Contact.Email</members>
        <members>Contact.FirstName</members>
        <members>Contact.LastName</members>
        <members>Contact.LastName</members>
        <members>Contact.Title</members>
        <name>CustomField</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomLabels</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <members>Account</members>
        <members>Contact</members>
        <name>CustomObject</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>Account-en_US</members>
        <members>Account-fr</members>
        <members>Contact-en_US</members>
        <members>Contact-fr</members>
        <name>CustomObjectTranslation</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Translations</name>
    </types>
    <version>38.0</version>
</Package>
```

Answer (score 1):

The metadata type for Custom Object Translations WILL show the translations for standard fields AFTER they have been customized. So I suspect that you don't have any translations yet. This becomes an issue if you want to create translations for standard fields, because the XML format and standard field names are strange. Here is the XML for a customized account name, for example:

```
<fields>
    <caseValues>
        <plural>false</plural>
        <value>Company Name</value>
    </caseValues>
    <caseValues>
        <plural>true</plural>
        <value>Company Names</value>
    </caseValues>
    <name>account_name</name>
    <startsWith>Vowel</startsWith>
</fields>
```